# Javascript proxy handle return statement

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I am using a proxy to handle the creation of an object without have to declare all "parent key" of the object.

```
var target = {};
var config = Proxy_ObjectCreator(target, handlers);
config.foo.bar = "Didn't need to create foo !";
return target;
```

Instead of this

```
var config = {
    foo : {
        bar : "needed to create foo ..."
    }
};
return config;
```

That part is fine and functional, but the issue I'm having is that it often happens that I forget that I need to return the target object instead of the proxy, which often creates really strange behaviors in my code.

For what I am aware of, there is no way for a Proxy object to handle the return statement. And so I'm trying to find a way to do exactly that. Something like that:

```
var config = Proxy_ObjectCreator({}, {
    get: (obj, prop, receiver) => {
        //Do stuff ...
    },
    set: (obj, prop, receiver) => {
        //Do stuff ...
    },
    return: () => {
        return this.target;
    }
});
config.foo.bar = "Didn't need to create a target obj and don't need to return it !";
return config;
```

Is there anyway to achieve that ?

Thanks you.

**Edit**

I'm using that to override configurations from a larger product to the client's specifications. So I'm working with hundreds of lines of configurations. Using a proxy allows me to structure the configuration file for future and clearer reading. It also allows me to group configuration's that can be all over the original config file together to comment on the reason why they are changed, without having to scroll up and down the object.

```
//Normal Object Case
function getClientConfigs() = {
    return {
        config1: {
            foo: {
                bar: {
                    foofoo: {
                        barbar: "value to override"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        // hundreds of other configs
        config2:{
           foo: "other value to override"
        }
    };
}

//With proxy
function getClientConfigs() = {
     var config = {};
     var proxy = Proxy_ObjectCreator(config, handlers);
     // Changing because client wanted that for x reason
     proxy.config1.foo.bar.foofoo.barbar = "value to override";
     proxy.config2.foo = "other value to override";
     return config;
}

$.extend(originalConfig, getClientConfigs());
```

Comment: That is not possible. But can you explain why you need the target object? Proxies are intended to hide the difference.

Comment: @trincot Because the proxy is used to instantiate the values in an object that will be returned at the end of a function. That object is used to overwrite an other object with the help of Jquery's extend function. I do that mostly out of laziness and convenience. I suppose in my context using a Proxy is really unnecessary

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, but it sounds like your question could be clarified by adding the corresponding code that would have the wrong behaviour if you returned the proxy.

Comment: Basically I'm overriding configurations from a product to the specifications of a client. For that purpose I use JQuery's extend function, which maybe might not be able to handle a proxy correctly, or maybe it's something somewhere in the product that is causing an issue.

Comment: Replace `$extend()` with `Object.assign()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to get the proxy recognise when it is returned from a function. (Btw, it also is returned from your `Proxy_ObjectCreator` function, so you'd need to explicitly ignore that…). No, that would get way too complicated.

But you could use a different design pattern - don't make `Proxy_ObjectCreator` a factory function, instead give it a callback so that the proxy cannot (easily) escape from the context:

```
function getClientConfigs() = {
     return withProxiedCreation({}, proxy => {
         proxy.config1.foo.bar.foofoo.barbar = "value to override";
         proxy.config2.foo = "other value to override";
     });
}
```

```
function withProxiedCreation(target, callback) {
    var proxy = new Proxy(target, handlers);
    callback(proxy);
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Nice and easy way to do what I want. No idea why I did not think of that Thanks !